# How to get the 'full database name' in MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'd like to have predictable names when creating indices so to cope with the length limitation on index names in MongoDB prior to v4.2, here's a method I've written:

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo.collection import Collection

def _ensure_index(collection: Collection, keys, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(keys, str):
        keys = [(keys, pymongo.ASCENDING)]
    name = kwargs.pop("name", pymongo.helpers._gen_index_name(keys))
    full_qualified_name = "%s.%s.$%s" % (collection.database.name, collection.name, name)
    if share.common.ARGS.get("--truncate-index-names", False) and len(full_qualified_name) > 127:
        # when using MongoDB prior to 4.2
        hex_crc = hex(binascii.crc32(full_qualified_name.encode("utf-8")))[2:]
        name = "%s_%s" % (
            name[: -(len(full_qualified_name) - 127 + len("_" + hex_crc))],
            hex_crc,
        )
    index_name = collection.create_index(keys, name=name, **kwargs)
    print("Created index %s.%s %s" % (collection.name, index_name, keys))
    return index_name
```

It works flawlessly when I'm using MongoDB community server. However, with MongoDB Atlas, I got `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: namespace name generated from index name "5d78be1aa6f2393b01ff006f_mydb.mycol.$index_keys_bla_bla_9392152b" is too long (127 byte max)`.

It seems the fully qualified database name has got a prefix in MongoDB Atlas (I guess one MongoDB server in Atlas can actually be shared by multiple instances, that's why they can provide cheap replicas etc but prefixes to database names are needed to ensure uniqueness). So I wonder how I can get the 'full database name' when using Atlas? The prefix seems to be transparent to Mongo Shell and pymongo most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does happens with the database in the shared clusters. But the prefix added will remain constant to all the database that you create in your cluster.

This means that you can count the bytes for this unique prefix and create index with respect to the unique prefix and not exceed the max bytes length which is 127 bytes.

Thanks

Comment: MongoDB support confirmed that the lengths of prefixes were consistent across all clusters and not prone to changes. So I guess this is the most straightforward way to go although imho it's quite hacky. BTW I was told that 'The prefix added to the database name in the shared cluster is same across all the databases which exist in that cluster', which made me wonder why it was needed then...